# Modify columns of data frames that are part of a list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I'm new to R, so sorry if this is something very basic.

I want to modify columns of data frames that are part of a list.

My original code is this:

```
eng17$hg <- substring(eng17$FT, 1, 1)  
eng16$hg <- substring(eng16$FT, 1, 1)  
eng17$ag <- substring(eng17$FT, 3, 3)  
eng16$ag <- substring(eng16$FT, 3, 3)
```

I want to be able to do this to all data frames that are part of a list, such as:

```
mylist = list(eng16, eng17)
```

I tried the following:

```
mylist[[1]]$hg <- substring(mylist[[1]]$FT, 1, 1)
mylist[[1]][hg] <- substring(mylist[[1]][FT], 1, 1)
mylist[[1]][6] <- substring(mylist[[1]][2], 1, 1)
```

But none of the above seemed to work. Ideally, I'd want to loop through all data frames in the list using the 'for' command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try next. Also, it woul be helpful if you `dput()` you data and include with your question.

```
#Function
change <- function(x)
{
  x$hg <- substring(x$FT, 1, 1)
  return(x)
}
#Application
lapply(change,mylist)
```